# Can not understand context of this in the code example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the below code snippet I am unclear on how **this** is being managed by React.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    private name: string

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.name = 'heisenberg'
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.sayMyName()}
                <button onClick={this.sayMyName}>Say My Name</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
    sayMyName(): string {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

It is first printing `heisenberg` in the page and when I am clicking the button it saying `this` is `undefined`, which is clear to me, that `React` does not automatically bind `this` to all the methods.

So, how exactly the context is getting changed once I am invoking the `sayMyName` method from directly inside `{}` and then from button click.

Adding screenshot

Before Button Click
[image]

After Button Click
[image]

Comment: private??? from my understanding JavaScript doesnt have any private keywords.  https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-private-class-fields/

Comment: I added typescript support

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Editing tags

Comment: thanks, I should have added typescript tag, but I do not think this behavior is causing by typescript

Comment: Just for readability. Not a lot of people can recognize type script.

Comment: Can you show some pictures? That would be helpful.

Comment: @Demon added screenshot

Comment: Alright I think the problem is that you are not binding the the button to the event handler.

Comment: @Demon, that I know how to fix it. My question is, what is happening with the `onClick` eventHandler, why is it losing the `this` context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An onclick event is asynchronous. When the callback is called, it's called from a global context, so `this` is set to the `window` object in non-strict mode, or undefined in strict mode.

To fix this, either create an arrow function in the render method (arrow functions take their value of `this` from the context in which they are defined), and pass that in to the button:

```
<button onClick={event => this.sayMyName(event)}>Say My Name</button>
```

Or create a bound version of sayMyName

```
constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.name = 'heisenberg';
    this.sayMyName = this.sayMyName.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: He already knows how to fix the problem. He just wanted to know why we have to bind `this` to object.

Comment: @Demon as i said, because it's an asynchronous callback that's called from a global context. What is it you would like me to add to my answer?

Comment: @NicholasTower, yes that is all I needed to know for now. Thanks for that. I was not aware of the information.

Comment: @ParnabSanyal, then consider accepting this answer.

Comment: Yes I will @devserkan

Answer (score 2):

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb

This person does a good article on your question. Basically, he's saying you can blame how JavaScript is like that.

In short, `this` context isnt lost... it more or less pointing to the global object